# What is the largest mathematics/mathematically-oriented library in the world?

Tags: soft-question

Just out of curiosity, what is the largest mathematics/mathematically-oriented library in the world? Is it open to the public? I would like to visit it sometime.

Comment: I only know of Courant's library.

Comment: (In that vein, I found a contemporaneous remark that Mittag-Leffler had the largest mathematics library in the world, but who knows how that was decided?)  So far, in searching, I've seen that the University of Illinois claims to have one of the world's largest, but the content at the Library of Congress is almost certainly rather larger, since publishers send books there.  In the age of digitization, this is probably becoming irrelevant.  A vast number of older books have already been released to the Internet and quite a lot of recent material is available by some level of online access.

Comment: Yeah, if the internet ain't the biggest, it soon will be!

Comment: As you specifically mention "open to the public" - I assume that the NSA does have a few shelves of "extra" math ...

Comment: I would guess your answer is near the top of this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_libraries

Comment: As a practical matter, the arXiv?

Answer (score 3):

Global Digital Mathematics Library (GDML)